# How find the specific file path for an excel file with PHPExcel and HTML input file?

Tags: php, html, excel, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I have an HTML input file type "button" and when I choose a file I can only get the name of the file and cannot get the full path which seems to be required from PHPExcel to be able to read the mentioned file, how could I make this work as the library is on the Server Side and the user has to pick a file in the Client side.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cant get complete path of the file from HTML due to security concerns, as the web browser don't have access to your local file system.

So you `select` the `file` and `upload` the file to `server`, and do process it.